# What is the story of Dionysus' shipwreck?

Tags: greek, dionysus

*Dionysus Shipwrecked* is a lost comedy, written either by Aristophanes or by Archippus. Regardless of authorship, the title suggests the play revolved around a story of Dionysus being shipwrecked. Has that story survived in any other form? Do we know anything about it?

The one story I know of Dionysus at sea, the one he's abducted by Tyrrhenian pirates, doesn't fit as there's no shipwreck involved.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to find any summaries of the plot, from which I deduce that it is lost to us. As for the title, [Emmanuela Bakola](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hs4UDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=Aristophanes%20Dionysus%20Shipwrecked&source=bl&ots=T6QdVB-tlv&sig=LT9dj2ZF4McChc4cPdQ9jpcEXIo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBnveflK3WAhUGRiYKHd72CEYQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=Aristophanes%20Dionysus%20Shipwrecked&f=false) suggests that in *Dionysus Shipwrecked*, like in the *Frogs*, Aristophanes (or Archippus) is playing off the close connections between Dionysus and the sea to suggest that the god is, in reality, "ignorant of the sea".